# Super Adventure Box Infantile Mode

Tags: guild-wars-2

I've collected all kind of guides and walkthroughs to help me get all the achievements in Super Adventure Box. I'm going to run through the complete SAB two or three times to make sure I get them all. For example, I have a playthrough where I cannot die, and I have another playthrough to get all the baubles, secret rooms and digsites.

I was wondering myself one thing though: Which achievements cannot be completed anymore when you enable Infantile Mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only achievement that I could not complete in Infantile Mode was "Scholar".

I am not sure which guides you are using but the best one I have found is the one from Dulfy.net which has everything collected together.

It also confirms that 'Scholar' cannot be completed in Infantile Mode.

http://dulfy.net/2013/04/01/gw2-super-adventure-box-guide/

Comment: I had the same site for the baubles, but I didn't bother to look for the others. I've found an other site with video's and pictures for the locations. It's handy to have it all in one! On topic, so every other achievement can possibly be gained on Infantile Mode? That's gonna be an easy run then.

Comment: @Joetjah It is a easy run but a little long. I decided to only do one zone at a time and worked on it slowly. Also yes I gained every other one in Infantile Mode.

Comment: Would you happen to know if you can get the achievement when you are with a partner? Say you need the achievement to get every bauble in the level. What happens if you and your partner pick them all up, but you only have for example half the baubles? Same goes for the digging?

Comment: I know digging the baubles were not part of the bauble achievement when I did them. If you are referring to just digging you could actually dig in the same place to get 100 digs. I did notice when playing through with a party that if everyone was not there to get a bauble it would disappear shortly after the first person picked it up. So this could hinder that achievement but I am not 100% certain on that.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? If there is a bauble worth 5 on a fixed place (so not for killing an enemy), and you play with a partner, and the partner picks it up. Does it stay there for me? Can I conclude from your comment I might have to pick it up within short time after my partner picks it up?

Comment: I should first preface this with I have not played the adventure box with a group since the first week so an update could have changed this.(Solo seems more efficient) I cannot confirm this is supposed to happen but I noticed this once or twice when I was in a group with other people. If someone else picked up a bauble it seemed to disappear after a few minutes. This could have just been a glitch. I would like to know if anyone else has noticed this.

Comment: I played the SAB yesterday with my brother. I can confirm that when I pick up a bauble and he walks over the same spot as well, I see +baubles popping up as animation. He receives the baubles just like I do. As an extra, he doesn't have a shovel but when I dig, we can both pick up the baubles. I haven't tested the bomb yet but I think we can both run in the secret room when I blow up the wall. We haven't tested the disappearing of items neither, but there is a new animation of a green sphere flying up in the sky slowly. Perhaps it's related (like a countdown).